# preg_match works in regexbuddy, not in php

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regexbuddy

Ok so I have this regex that I created and it works fine in RegexBuddy but not when I load it into php. Below is an example of it.

Using RegexBuddy I can get it to works with this:

```
\[code\](.*)\[/code\]
```

And checking the dot matches newline, I added the case insensitive, but it works that way as well.

Here is the php:

```
$q = "[code]<div>html code to display on screen</div>[/code]";

$pattern = '/\[code\](.*)\[/code\]/si';

$m = preg_match($pattern, $q, $code);
```

So you can see I am using [code][/code] and then once I can extract this I will run htmlentities() on it to display instead of render html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're including the forward slash in the middle of your pattern (/code).  Either escape it or delimit your pattern with something else (I prefer !).

Answer (score 2):

When transferring your regular expression from RegexBuddy to PHP, either generate a source code snippet on the Use tab, or click the Copy button on the toolbar at the top, and select to copy as a PHP preg string.  Then RegexBuddy will automatically add the delimiters and flags that PHP needs, without leaving anything unescaped.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't escape the closing marker `/`

Escaping the backslashes wouldn't hurt either:

```
$pattern = "/\\[code\\](.*)\\[\\/code\\]/si";
```

PHP lets you choose any characters as the RegEx delimiter, so I'll often use a character which isn't also used in the regex, like `@`.

```
$pattern = "@\\[code\\](.*)\\[/code\\]@si";
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$pattern = '/\[code\](.*)\[\/code\]/si';
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape the forward slash in /code

```
$pattern = '/\[code\](.*)\[\/code\]/si';
```

Also, realize the matches are stored in $code, not $m

Edit: Beaten to it :p

Comment: yup $m was just part of debug to know if it was true or false